# How do I search device using core Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, swift3, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

In my iOS app, I want to search device using swift 3. How do I implement this functionality in my app using core Bluetooth?

Comment: You need to better understanding of Multipeer Connectivity. This tutorial will help you: https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/networking/multipeer-connectivity/

Answer (score 0):

this below code i what i wrote from rearching in internet and help of my friends to list bluetooth devices and connect to heart rate measure service

```
class HRMViewController: UIViewController {

 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var cbCentralManager: CBCentralManager?
var cbPeripheral: CBPeripheral?
 var discoveredPeripherals = [CBPeripheral]()
var connected = ""
var bodyData = ""
var manufacturer = ""
var deviceData = ""
var heartRate: UInt16 = 0
var localNameArray = [String]()

var pulseTimer: Timer?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    tableView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
    tableView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    let centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    self.cbCentralManager = centralManager



}

}

 extension HRMViewController : CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {


    let localName = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey] as? String ?? ""
    if localName.count > 0 {


        if RSSI.intValue > signalStrengthMax {

            if let index = self.discoveredPeripherals.index(of: peripheral) {
                self.discoveredPeripherals.remove(at: index)
                self.localNameArray.remove(at: index)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

            return
        }

        if RSSI.intValue < signalStrengthMin {

            if let index = self.discoveredPeripherals.index(of: peripheral) {
                self.discoveredPeripherals.remove(at: index)
                self.localNameArray.remove(at: index)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

            return
        }

        print("Discovered: \(peripheral.name ?? "a device") with udid: \(peripheral.identifier) at \(RSSI)")



        if !(self.discoveredPeripherals.contains(peripheral)) {
            self.discoveredPeripherals.append(peripheral)
            self.localNameArray.append(localName)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {

    peripheral.delegate = self
    peripheral.discoverServices(nil)

    self.connected = "Connected: \((peripheral.state == .connected) ? "Yes" : "No")"


}

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    if central.state != .poweredOn {
        return
    }

    if central.state == .poweredOn {
        let deviceService = CBUUID(string: HRMConstants.Services.deviceInfoUUID)
        let heartRateService = CBUUID(string: HRMConstants.Services.heartRateUUID)
        let services = [deviceService,heartRateService]
        cbCentralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: services, options: nil)
    }
}


func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {

    for service in peripheral.services ?? [CBService]() {
        peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
    }

}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

    if service.uuid == CBUUID(string: HRMConstants.Services.heartRateUUID) {
        for character in service.characteristics ?? [CBCharacteristic]() {

            if character.uuid == CBUUID(string: HRMConstants.Characteristics.measurementUUID) {
                self.cbPeripheral?.setNotifyValue(true, for: character)
            }
            else if character.uuid == CBUUID(string: HRMConstants.Characteristics.bodyLocationUUID) {
                self.cbPeripheral?.readValue(for: character)
            }
        }
    }

    if service.uuid == CBUUID(string: HRMConstants.Services.deviceInfoUUID) {
        for character in service.characteristics ?? [CBCharacteristic]() {
            if character.uuid == CBUUID(string: HRMConstants.Characteristics.manufacturerNameUUID) {
                self.cbPeripheral?.readValue(for: character)
            }
        }
    }

}


func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

    if characteristic.uuid == CBUUID(string: HRMConstants.Characteristics.measurementUUID) {
        self.getHeartRateData(for: characteristic, error: error)
    }

    if characteristic.uuid == CBUUID(string: HRMConstants.Characteristics.manufacturerNameUUID) {
        self.getManufacturerName(for: characteristic)
    }

    else if characteristic.uuid == CBUUID(string: HRMConstants.Characteristics.bodyLocationUUID) {
        self.getBodyLocation(for: characteristic)
    }
}
 }

 extension HRMViewController {

func getHeartRateData(for characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {


    if let _ = error {
        print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ??  "Unknown")")
        return
    }

    guard let value = characteristic.value else { return }

    let bpm : UInt16
    if (value[0] & 0x01) == 0 {
        bpm = UInt16(value[1])
    } else {
        bpm = UInt16(littleEndian: value.subdata(in: 1..<3).withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee } )
    }

    heartRate = bpm
    doHeartBeat()
    pulseTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60.0 / Double(heartRate), target: self, selector: #selector(self.doHeartBeat), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)


    /*
    var reportData = [UInt8](value)
    var bpm: UInt16 = 0
    if (reportData[0] & 0x01) == 0 {
        bpm = UInt16(reportData[1])
    }
    else {
         bpm = CFSwapInt16LittleToHost(UInt16(reportData[1]))
    }
    heartRate = bpm

    doHeartBeat()
    pulseTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60.0 / Double(heartRate), target: self, selector: #selector(self.doHeartBeat), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    */


}

func getManufacturerName(for characteristic: CBCharacteristic) {

    guard let value = characteristic.value else { return }
    let manufacturerName = String(data: value, encoding: .utf8)


}

func getBodyLocation(for characteristic: CBCharacteristic) {

    guard let value = characteristic.value else { return }
    var location = ""
    // 1
    var bodyData = [UInt8](value)
    if !bodyData.isEmpty {
        let bodyLocation: UInt8 = bodyData[0]
        // 2
        location = "Body Location: \(bodyLocation == 1 ? "Chest" : "Undefined")"
        // 3
    }
    else {
        // 4
        location = "Body Location: N/A"
    }
    print(location)
}

@objc func doHeartBeat() {


}


}

 extension HRMViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    cell?.textLabel?.text = "\(localNameArray[indexPath.row]) \(discoveredPeripherals[indexPath.row].identifier )"
    return cell!

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let newPeripheral = discoveredPeripherals[indexPath.row]

    if let _ = cbPeripheral { // had a device selected already
        if newPeripheral != cbPeripheral! { // clean up old peripheral
            self.cleanUp()
        }
    }

    cbPeripheral = newPeripheral

    self.cbCentralManager?.stopScan()
    cbPeripheral?.delegate = self
    self.cbCentralManager?.connect(cbPeripheral!, options: nil)


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return discoveredPeripherals.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 45.0
}

func cleanUp() {

    if !(cbPeripheral!.state == .connected) { // Don't do anything if we're not connected
        return
    }

    if let services = self.cbPeripheral!.services {
        for eachService in services {
            if let characteristics = eachService.characteristics {
                for eachCharacteristic in characteristics {
                    if eachCharacteristic.uuid.isEqual(CBUUID(string: HRMConstants.Characteristics.bodyLocationUUID)) {
                        if eachCharacteristic.isNotifying {
                            self.cbPeripheral?.setNotifyValue(false, for: eachCharacteristic)
                        }
                    }

                    if eachCharacteristic.uuid.isEqual(CBUUID(string: HRMConstants.Characteristics.manufacturerNameUUID)) {
                        if eachCharacteristic.isNotifying {
                            self.cbPeripheral?.setNotifyValue(false, for: eachCharacteristic)
                        }
                    }

                    if eachCharacteristic.uuid.isEqual(CBUUID(string: HRMConstants.Characteristics.measurementUUID)) {
                        if eachCharacteristic.isNotifying {
                            self.cbPeripheral?.setNotifyValue(false, for: eachCharacteristic)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    self.cbCentralManager?.cancelPeripheralConnection(self.cbPeripheral!)
    self.cbPeripheral = nil
}

 }
```

and for constants

```
struct HRMConstants {

struct Services {
    static let deviceInfoUUID = "180A"
    static let heartRateUUID = "180D"
}

struct Characteristics {

    static let measurementUUID = "2A37"
    static let bodyLocationUUID = "2A38"
    static let manufacturerNameUUID = "2A29"
}

}
```

with this you will get the basic idea and then you can try it for yourself

see for ble doc for different bluetooth services